# não consigo comparar as strings

Tags: c

Cadastrei o codigo do cliente e agora preciso solicitar novamente so que preciso verificar se ha ou não codigo cadastrado, só que mesmo que os codigos sejam diferentes o  diz que ha codigo cadastrado.

**Questão:**
3 - Calcular o valor da venda do veículo     Solicitar:  Placa do veículo (verificar se tem veículo cadastrado) Código do cliente (verificar se tem cliente cadastrado) O valor de fábrica do veículo Verificar se o cliente quer comprar o veículo à vista ou a prazo

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include <string.h>
main (){

    char aux[50];
    int opcao;

    printf("################################");printf("\n#       seja bem vindo         #");printf("\n#                              #"); printf("\n################################"); 
    struct cliente
    {
        char codigo[50];
        char nome[50];
        char endereco[50];
        float salario;

    };

    struct cliente cadastro;
    cadastro.codigo;
    cadastro.nome;
    cadastro.endereco;
    cadastro.salario;
    struct veiculo
    {
        char placa[50];
        char marca[50];
        char ano[50];
        char combustivel[50];
    };

    struct veiculo cadastro1;
    cadastro1.placa;
    cadastro1.marca;
    cadastro1.ano;
    cadastro1.combustivel;

    do{
        printf("\n1 - Cadastrar Novo Cliente");
        printf("\n2 - Cadastro Novo Veiculo");
        printf("\n3 - Calcular o Valor Da Venda Do Veiculo");
        printf("\n0 - Finalizar\n");
        printf(" \nSelecione uma opcao por favor: ");
        scanf("%d", &opcao);
        fflush(stdin);

        if(opcao==1){
            system("cls");
            printf("#######################################################");printf("\n# Voce selecionou a opcao 1 - Cadastrar Novo Cliente  #");printf("\n#                                                     #"); printf("\n#######################################################"); 

            printf("\n\nDigite o codigo Para o cliente: ");
            gets(cadastro.codigo);
            fflush(stdin);

            printf("\nDigite o Nome Do Cliente: ");
            gets(cadastro.nome);
            fflush(stdin);

            printf("\nDigite o Endereco Do Cliente: ");
            gets(cadastro.endereco);
            fflush(stdin);

            printf("\nDigite o Salario Do Cliente: ");
            scanf("%.2f",cadastro.salario);
            printf("\n\n");
            fflush(stdin);

            printf("\n\nCliente Cadastrado\n\n");
            fflush(stdin);

            printf(" \nPrecione Enter Para Volta ao Menu Principal.... ");
            getchar();
            system("cls");
            main();
        }
        else{
            system("cls");
            if(opcao==2){
                printf("#######################################################");printf("\n# Voce selecionou a opcao 2 - Cadastro Novo Veiculo   #");printf("\n#                                                     #"); printf("\n#######################################################"); 

                fflush(stdin);
                printf("\n\nDigite a Placa do veiculo: ");
                gets(cadastro1.placa);
                fflush(stdin);

                printf("\nDigite a Marca Do Veiculo: ");
                gets(cadastro1.marca);
                fflush(stdin);

                printf("\nDigite o Ano Do Veiculo:");
                gets(cadastro1.ano);
                fflush(stdin);

                printf("\nDigite o Tipo de Combustivel: ");
                scanf("%c",cadastro1.combustivel);
                fflush(stdin);


                printf("\n\nVeiculo Cadastrado\n\n");
                fflush(stdin);

                printf(" \nPrecione Enter Para Volta ao Menu Principal.... ");
                getchar();
                system("cls");
                main();
                break;
            }
            else{
                if(opcao==3){              
                    printf("\n\n insira o codigo do cliente");
                    gets(aux);
                    if (strcmp(aux,cadastro.codigo))
                    printf ("\n\n  ha codigo cadastrado");
                    else printf ("\n\ nao ha codigo cadastrado.");
                    printf(" \nPrecione Enter Para Volta ao Menu Principal.... ");
                    getchar();
                    system("cls");
                    main();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }   

    }while (opcao != 9 || opcao < 9);

    return 0;     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu erro esta na maneira na qual você esta usando a função strcmp.

Essa função tem essa assinatura:

```
int strcmp ( const char * str1, const char * str2 );
```

Logo ela retorna um int.

Funcionamento dela: ela retorna três valores possíveis.

"<" 0 (menor que zero) -  se o primeiro caractere diferente nas duas "strings" for menor na primeira "string" em relação a segunda "string". (Essa ideia de menor esta relacionado aos valores de cada caractere na tabela ASCII)

0 - se as "strings" forem iguais

">" 0 (maior que zero) se o primeiro caractere diferente nas duas "strings" for maior na primeira "string" em relação a segunda "string".

Resumindo se for menor que 0 a primeira "string" e menor que a segunda, se for maior que 0 a primeira "string" e maior que segunda. E se for 0 ambas são iguais.

Sugiro trocar seu if para:

```
if (!strcmp(aux,cadastro.codigo)) // 0 é corrospondente a false e ! é basicamente if (strcmp(aux,cadastro.codigo) == false)
                    printf ("\n\n  ha codigo cadastrado");
```

Seu if estava ao contrario, você estava verificando se o valor era diferente e e retornando que ele era igual caso fosse diferente, dessa maneira se strcmp retornar 0, ou seja, elas são iguais, ai ele printa "ha codigo cadastrado", caso o falor for != 0 então ele vai para o else.

Espero ter sido sucinto e que a resposta te ajude

Comment: então, parece que o strcmp não esta puxando a string do struct  pois  mesmo com o codigo acima citado não rodou , mesmo não cadastrando  codigo ele conta como há codigo

Comment: Estranho porque testei aqui e funcionou normalmente, e olhando não vejo mais nenhum erro relacionado a esse trecho

Comment: tu pode me mandar o teu codigo  so a parte do if para analisar ? qual compilador está usando.

Comment: eu não uso Windows uso linux, compilo direto pelo terminal com gcc, o if ta do mesmo jeito que eu coloquei ali

Comment: hum, sem o else rodou